# How do I have a subclassed UIGestureRecognizer class call a selector on a view

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view called GameViewController. I didn't set it up but it seems to be a UIKit view with an embedded EAGL view.

I set up gesture recognizers for tap and swipe on my GameViewController. They work great, except the method I set up as a selector for tap (a function within GameViewController) gets called on touchesEnded, not touchesBegan.

Only way to get at the touchesBegan function is to subclass.

So, I subclassed UITapGestureRecognizer, created a touchesBegan function, and NSLogs in there get called on touch down. However, I can't call any functions in GameViewController from the UITapGestureRecognizer subclass. (Class method +METHODIWANTTOCALL not found).

I realize I need "references" back and forth but what should they be? Or is this totally the wrong approach? Do I delegate? (I'm new to that) What is the best way to have a method within GameViewController called from this UITapGesture subclass?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your GameViewController is a singleton class (only one instance of this class in the app). You can have a class method in GameViewController that returns the instance of the singleton. Then you can just the method regularly:

In Recognizer:
`GameViewController* myController = [GameViewController getInstance];
[myController handleTouchBegin];`

Alternatively, you can define your handleTouchBegin as a class method if it does not need to know any internal state:

`[GameViewController handleTouchBegin];`

Comment: GameViewController is definitely a singleton, I'm having a hard time with the code to return an instance though. All the examples seem to be for allocating the instance...and obviously 'GameViewController' is already allocated.

Comment: I guess what I should actually say is that there is only one instance of the GameViewController but it's not set up as a singleton, using the design patterns I've seen.

Comment: Just create a wrapper around GameViewController called MyGameViewController. Alternatively, use your own class as the class that can retrieve the singleton. Wherever you are initializing and storing GameViewController, create a class method called "getGameViewController". Then call `[SomeClassThatOwnsController getGameViewController].`